# replace all 0's in a list with numpy.nan

Tags: python, list

I have a list with 0's in it that I want to change to np.nan for calculations in doing. I am trying to do the following which only replaces the first 0:

```
l = [0,2,3,4,0]
l[l == 0] = np.nan
print l
[nan,2,3,4,0]
```

Is there a way to do this substitution for every item in the list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use numpy vector boolean indexing or comparisons with a Python list, so your `l == 0` is simply giving you 0.  It's only a fluke it works even partially, because you happened to have 0 as the first element.

```
>>> l = [0,2,3,4,0]
>>> l == 0
False
>>> int(l == 0)
0
>>> l[l == 0] = 999
>>> l
[999, 2, 3, 4, 0]
```

You could use a list comprehension and a ternary:

```
>>> l = [0,2,3,4,0]
>>> l = [np.nan if x == 0 else x for x in l]
>>> l
[nan, 2, 3, 4, nan]
```

(If you were working with numpy arrays, vector comparisons and assignments *would* work, but you can't mix integers and floats (such as np.nan) too nicely.)

Answer (score 5):

You can just use the built in map:

```
l = map(lambda number: np.nan if number == 0 else number, l)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = 0 if l[i] == np.nan else l[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using numpy: your notation works, if `l` was a numpy.array and not a list. However, it only works, if your entries are not integers, e.g. floats:

```
array = np.array(list, dtype=float)
array[array == 0] = np.nan
```

Now array looks like this:

```
array([ nan, 2.,  3., 4., nan])
```

If you really need a list, then

```
l = list(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice elegant way to do it:

```
l = [x or np.nan for x in l]
```